# Can I reference an object within a collection by it's name?

Tags: c#, collections, dictionary

I have a Collection object (based on System.Collections.CollectionBase) but to access the values of objects within that collection, I have to use the index currently. Is it possible to get the values based on the name of the object within the collection?

For example, instead of...

```
MyCollection[0].Value
```

... how can I do something along the lines of:

```
MyCollection["Birthday"].Value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the this[] accessor

```
public Item this[string name]
{
get
{
  // iterate through the elements of the collection 
  //and return the one that matches with name
}
}
```

Have this getter property on your MyCollectionClass

Answer (score 4):

In order to do this you would need to have a `Dictionary<string,object>`. Unfortunately collections only allow random access by index.

You could do something like this:

```
var item = MyCollection
              .Where(x => x.SomeProp == "Birthday")
              .FirstOrDefault();

// careful - item could be null here
var value = item.Value;
```

But this will be nowhere near as efficient as random access by index.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) which allows you to access its element by a key. So if the key in your example is a string you could use `Dictionary<string, TValue>`.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think objects in a collection have names? They don't. What you can do is use a `Dictionary<String, SomethingElse>` to enable your syntax.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear that the 'Name' is held as one of the properties of the objects in the Collection.

Answer (score 2):

As others has said, you need a [Dictionary<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) to do that. If you cannot change the code that provides the collection, you can use LINQ's [ToDictionary()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277.aspx) method to convert it to a dictionary yourself:

```
var dict = MyCollection.ToDictionary(obj => obj.Name);
```

From there on, you can do:

```
var value = dict["Birthday"].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

One workaround could be

```
private const int BIRTHDAY = 0;

var value = MyCollection["Birthday"].Value;
```